# Force https to http redirect except for Wordpress /wp-admin directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Our `HTTPS` site is indexed on Google. We need this redirected to `HTTP`. We're using the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

to redirect `https` to `http`, and it works fine.

However, I want to exclude all of Wordpress admin from the `https` to `http` redirect, as I'd like to keep Wordpress admin working over `https`, so I added:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin
```

taking the .htaccess code to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately this does not work, and trying to load `/wp-admin` over `https` results in too many redirects and the Wordpress dashboard does not load.

> www.example.com redirected you too many times.

Would appreciate some help in excluding /wp-admin from the `https` to `http` redirect.

Comment: Is it a good idea to redirect https traffic to http - with the former the user is expecting secure communication whereas they get insure communication

Comment: Agreed, but a Wordpress plugin `Slider Revolution` is not displaying slides on `https`, hence the need to revert back to `http`, as the slider was a key part of the home page design.

Comment: Why not fix the plugin?

Comment: I've tried. Plugin support is unable to resolve the problem either.

Comment: Whats not working with the plugin @Steve? If the images are being blocked because they are non https then you likely just need to update the images to use https.

Comment: Hi @Jrod. If I switch the front end to `https` and use the [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin to search for all instances of `http://www.example.com` in the `wp_revslider_sliders`, `wp_revslider_slides` tables, (so I can replace with `https://www.example.com`) no instances of `http://www.example.com` are found.

Comment: After I switch the front end to `https`, the home page rev slider is loading images over `https`, but those images don't display. Checking the Chrome console, I can't see any rev slider resources being loaded over `http`. Rev Slider support can't help.

Comment: It turns out when another plugin is deactivated, the home page slider will display over `https`. That other plugin is only required for one page - the contact page, so I need to figure out how to load a plugin on that page only, so it is not loaded on the home page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, this should force everything to HTTP except for the directory wp-admin:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(wp-admin)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(wp-admin)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have problems with the above, you can try this also:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Mr Thick Guru. (first option worked)

Comment: Glad I could help :)